# Ошибка при доступе к закрытому статическому свойству

Tags: php, ооп, static

Изучаю ООП и наткнулся в сети на интересный пример:

```
class Foo
{
    private static $name = 'Foo';

    public static function getName(){
        return static::$name;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    private static $name = 'Bar';
}

echo Bar::getName();
```

Не могу понять, почему при выполнении его на сервере (PHP 7.2.1) я получаю ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property Bar::$name in /home/......
>   Error: Cannot access private property Bar::$name in /home/.....

Я понимаю этот пример так:
Класс Bar наследует **публичный** статический метод getName, соответственно, мы можем его вызвать в клиенском коде. Закрытое свойство $name также переопределено в классе Bar и, несмотря на то, что свойство $name закрытое внутри метода getName мы имеем к нему доступ, соответственно, вызов метода Bar::getName() должен вывести переменную $name на экран. Почему я получаю ошибку?

Также очень смущает вызов static::$name внутри метода public static function getName. В литературе сказано: static позволяет обращаться к статическим переменным даже из нестатического контекста. Здесь же мы обращаемся к статической переменной внутри статического метода, это корректно и правильно?? Не умеснее здесь было бы использовать self::$name ?

Comment: `self::name` вам без всяких ошибок `foo` выведет. вы `self::` с `$this` случаем не попутали? `self` и `static` по сути одно и тоже, с небольшим нюансом. Статик переменная/метод связана не с экземляром класса а с самими классом, вообще без разницы откуда к ней обращаются, из статического контекста или нет.  ну а по сабжу, то что публичный метод одного класса не может обратиться к приватному свойству другого вроде обычный концепт.

Comment: @teran автору похоже нужно получить `Bar` _(т.к. он перезаписывает свойство $name в дочернем классе этим значением)_ Если я не ошибаюсь _(а если ошибаюсь - поправьте, плиз)_ , ему ещё понадобится перегрузка родительского метода getName() в дочернем, и тогда он сможет получить доступ к приватному свойству **$name** в дочернем классе. Но только это, по-моему, быдлокод.

Comment: @SashaPetrov в дополнение к комментариям выше, вам может ещё пригодится чтение на тему "[Позднее статическое связывание](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)" , т.к. в вашем примере именно это и реализовано.

Answer (score 1):

Статическое свойство относится к классу и если вы его делаете приватный, то объекты не могут получить к нему доступ, все вполне логично.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю справедливо ли это по отношению именно к ООП в php.

Напишу ответ с точки зрения общих принципов ООП программирования.

1. К приватным свойствам и методам имеет доступ только класс, где они
   объявлены.
2. Статические методы НЕ наследуются. Для возможности наследования
   нужно объявить виртуальный метод.